# Painting over seams

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Can I paint continuously on top of a sim? It seems like a problem. See the image

[image]

The black lining is unintended and seems like it is coming because of the seams that went through that line.

Comment: Perhaps try to increase the Bleed value in the Tools panel > Options > Project Paint, when you are in Texture Paint mode

Comment: @moonboots what the bleed value is? And how would it help?

Comment: the brush will paint a bit out of the UVmap island, so make sure you have a bit margin